# Methods to prevent overwriting the internal functions provided

Tags: javascript, plugins, interface

I have the following code for a mini framework. How do i "bulletproof" my code so that a possible delinquent developer will not break it? I summarized what the code does in the comments, and here's [a demo for clarification](http://jsfiddle.net/sTjqR/1/)

```
var kit = (function() {
    'use strict';

    //internal cache
    var internal = {
        core: {}
    }

    //external interface for extensions
    //let's say we provide a hook for error handling from the core
    var external = {
        core: {
            error: {
                addListener: function(callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //externally available options
    var core = {
        //build extension by creating an instance of the passed function
        //providing it the core interface, and 
        //then store the instance in the cache
        extend: function(extensionName, extensionDefinition) {
            var newExtension = new extensionDefinition(external.core)
            internal.core[extensionName] = newExtension;
        }
    };

    //expose
    return {
        core: {
            extend: core.extend
        },
        _internal: internal,
        _external: external
    }

}());

//let's say two developers built these extensions

//developer1 builds his code
kit.core.extend('extension1', function(core) {
    core.error.addListener(function() {
        alert('test');
    })

    //developer1 intentionally kills the whole error interface
    core.error = null;

});

//now, the other scripts cannot use the error interface
//because some delinquent developer killed it
kit.core.extend('extension2', function(core) {

    //core.error is no more!

    core.error.addListener(function() {
        alert('test');
    })
});
```

how do i do this so that every extension has an isolated "copy" of the `core` external functions so no matter what they do to it, it does not affect the other extensions?

A side question, if i may add: Is there a better way/approach to structuring this code?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't "bulletproof" JavaScript.  The language is too permissive.  Even built-in functions provided by the browser (`alert()`, `parseInt()`, etc.) can be arbitrarily replaced.  Typically the best you can do is obfuscate your code before you deploy it.

Comment: @aroth i know that there is no kevlar thick enough to prevent it. but i would like to know if there's a better way to isolate breakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make your code safe from accidental interferance, then:

```
(function(window, undefined) { 
  …
}(window));
```

is not how to do it. You don't know what *window* references in the global context (it may not exist at all), the **only** reference you know is safe is *this*, which must reference the global object, so:

```
(function(global, undefined) { 
  …
}(this));
```

is safer.

Nothing can access your code inside the IIFE, so it is as safe as javascript can be, but it is certainly not secure. Any system that delivers its source to the client is inherently insecure.

Comment: i wasn't talking about the IFFE. i meant the `kit.core.extend` and the `core` interface it provided. that `core` is free to modify, thus any developer trying to be delinquent, will break the rest of the code. i'm trying to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using defineProperty and its cousins. With this you can fine tune the capabilities of the properties in your public object and prevent anyone form changing them. For complete details see http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.6